# How to setup Cloudfront to list directory structure from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have setup Cloudfront distribution as S3 bucket as my origin. I am able to access individual files on my S3 bucket, like - http://xxx.cloudfront.net/x1/xxxx.txt
but I am not able to view directory structure in the Root url - 
http://xxx.cloudfront.net/
Directory list: 
x1
x2
x3

Is there a way to enable directory listing in cloudfront? Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thank you so much folks!

Comment: Could you post the bucket policy?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an S3 origin (i.e. not S3 bucket website hosting), then make sure that your bucket policy contains the `s3:ListBucket` permission for your CloudFront Origin Access Identity, like the following:

```
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity EYOURID"
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
        }
```

The resource must be the ARN of the bucket.

Note that the directory listing will be in XML format which may or may not be desirable.