# is there any way to view directory structure of s3 folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Is there any way to list bucket  folders on cloudfront url ? I have created a url like this

https://xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/  on this I want to list down all s3 files . currently getting error of index.html file not found .  if I open a file like   https://xxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/image.html  it's working fine.

my bucket policy is like this :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
        }
    ]
}
```

any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61786823/how-to-setup-cloudfront-to-list-directory-structure-from-s3-bucket

Comment: @jarmod that didn't work. updated question